# A topological detail in the definition of Lie group

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups

A Lie group $ G $ is an $r$-times-differentiable manifold endowed with a group structure, i.e. with an associative binary operation

$$
 \mu:\quad G\times G \longrightarrow G :\qquad\left\{x\,, y\right\} \longmapsto x\centerdot y
 $$

and an inversion operation

$$
 \zeta:\quad G \longrightarrow G :\qquad g \longmapsto g^{-1}~~,
 $$

both of which are $r$-times-differentiable.

Now take the inverses of all points residing in an open set $U$:
$$
\tilde{U}\equiv\zeta(U)~~.
$$
How to show that $\tilde{U}$ is open, i.e. that the inversion $\zeta$ is continuous?

To be more specific, consider a homeomorphism
$$
\alpha:\quad U\subseteq G\;\longrightarrow\;W\subseteq{\mathbb{R}}^N~~.
$$

If $\tilde{U}$ too is open (which I wish to prove), there should exist a homeomorphism
$$
\beta:\quad \tilde{U}\subseteq G\;\longrightarrow\;W\subseteq{\mathbb{R}}^N~~.
$$

By saying that the inversion $\zeta$ is differentiable, we actually imply that differentiable is
$$
\beta^{-1}\circ\zeta\circ\alpha~~.
$$
Is that correct?

Would it be right to say that, by assuming the differentiability, I thereby imply the existence of $\beta$ and, thence, the fact that $\tilde {U}$ is open?

Comment: Well, a differentiable map is in particular continuous.

Comment: I am trying to show this. Consider a homeomorphism 
$$
\alpha:\quad U\subseteq G\;\longrightarrow\;W\subseteq{\mathbb{R}}^N~~.
$$ 

If  $\tilde{U}$ is open too (which I wish to prove), there should exist a homeomorphism
$$
\beta:\quad \tilde{U}\subseteq G\;\longrightarrow\;W\subseteq{\mathbb{R}}^N~~.
$$ 

By saying that $\zeta$ is differentiable, we imply that differentiable is 
$$
\beta^{-1}\circ\zeta\circ\alpha~~.
$$ 
Is that right?

Is it right to say that, by assuming the differentiability, I imply the existence of $\beta$ and, thence, the fact that $\tilde {U}$ is open?

Comment: $\zeta=\zeta^{-1}$, so by assuming that $\zeta$ is continuous, we get $\zeta^{-1}$ is continuous, hence $\overline{U}=\zeta(U)=(\zeta^{-1})^{-1}(U)$ is open.

Comment: @Thorgott I never said that $\zeta$ is continuous. Should I add this into the definition of a Lie group, as a separate condition?

Comment: No, as has already been noted by Eric Wofsey and Henno Brandsma, a differentiable function is automatically continuous.

Comment: @Thorgott In calculus, a differentiable f is icontinuous. Here, however, we have two f's. One,
$$
\beta^{-1}\circ\zeta\circ\alpha~:\quad{\mathbb{R}}^N\longrightarrow{\mathbb{R}}^N,
$$
can be differentiable (and thence continuous - in the calculus sense). The other,
$$
\zeta~:\quad\tilde{U}\longrightarrow\tilde{U},
$$
cannot be differentiable as it links open sets, not coordinate patches. It can be continuous, in the topological sense. So we return to my question: by saying that $\zeta$ is "differentiable", do we mean that it is $\beta^{-1}\circ\zeta\circ\alpha$  .who is differentiable?

Comment: The function $\zeta\colon G\rightarrow G$ is differentiable by hypothesis, hence continuous by definition and then so is $\zeta^{-1}=\zeta$. Just being open does not guarantee homeomorphisms $\alpha,\beta$ as you want to exist. What is true is that $\zeta$ is differentiable iff $\psi\circ\zeta\circ\phi^{-1}$ is differentiable in the calculus sense for all charts $\phi,\psi$.

Answer (score 1):

A differentiable function is continuous (standard analysis fact) and so $\zeta$ (being self-inverse) is a homeomorphism and so an open map.